# Black holes from gravitational collapse without matter

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-collapse

A collapsing star or mass shell or photon shell can eventually form a black hole. Are there any examples of BH formed from purely gravitational condensation of energy, like from focused gravitational waves?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3880

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example you can have the [Vaidya metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaidya_metric), which represents formation of a black hole from a cloud of photons.

You can also get similar solutions using gravitational radiation. Singularities are a generic occurrence in general relativity. In some loose sense, if you choose random initial conditions, black holes will occur with unit probability, even if there are no matter fields.

Comment: Do you have references on black hole formation using gravitational radiation? and also about singularities are a generic occurrence in general relativity?